# Wordpress transients for a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, cache, transient

I have a small shortcode which basically takes data from a JSON file and displays it on a page. The data in JSON is updated weekly, how can I use a transient so the data for the current week is cached?

Here is my shortcode

```
function week_agenda() {
        $days = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_file'));
        unset($days[0]);
        ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Title </th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($days as $data) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $data[0]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead of the line in wich you define `$days` (your second line):

```
$transient = get_transient( 'your_transient_key' );

if( !$transient ):

    $days = file_get_contents( 'json_file' );

    set_transient( 'your_transient_key', $days, DAY_IN_SECONDS*7 );


else:

    $days = $transient;

endif;

$days = json_decode( $days );

...
```

May be a bit rough but you get the idea.

Comment: Perfect, works fine :)

Comment: Glad i could help ;) I think there is no further explanation of the code necessary or is it?

Answer (score 5):

I add it the transient name to a variable to handle it easier.

Next, I check if the return value from the [`get_transient`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_transient/) is false and update the variable name and the transient.
You can try this one:

```
    $transient_name = 'cached_json_data';
    if ( false === ( $json_data = get_transient( $transient_name ) ) ) {
      $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_file'));
      set_transient( $transient_name, $json_data, WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
    }

//normal code
```

**set_transient**

> You do not need to serialize values. If the value needs to be
>   serialized, then it will be serialized before it is set.

Constants WP 3.5+

```
MINUTE_IN_SECONDS  = 60 (seconds)
HOUR_IN_SECONDS    = 60 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS
DAY_IN_SECONDS     = 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS
WEEK_IN_SECONDS    = 7 * DAY_IN_SECONDS
MONTH_IN_SECONDS   = 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS
YEAR_IN_SECONDS    = 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS
```

Comment: +1 for the compact sytax and the detailed answer. Could also be the accepted answer.